# How to convert data from file into a structure in C?

Tags: c, datetime, data-structures, structure

I have to make a function that converts data(time) from file into structure with use of other function. So take this from the file (2018-06-01 01:00:00) and convert it into structure. 
First is year then month, day, hour, min and sec.

I am kinda new to this so I don't know how to properly use strtok fro parsing.

Data in file look like this:

- id;sensor_id;time;m3

  12899;1;2018-06-01 01:00:00;0.0000

  150362;222;2019-11-14 14:00:00;0.2465

  150369;35;2019-11-14 15:00:00;0.2550

  . . .

And this is how the structre should looks like.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct { 
int year; 
int month; 
int day; 
int hour; 
int min; 
int sec; 
int dayInWeek; 
}tDateTime;
```

And declarations of functions. I have already solved the "giveDayInWeek" function.

```
tDateTime dejDateTime(char* datetime) //converts input from text file (2018-05-01 01:00:00) into structure, with using giveDayInWeek

int giveDayInWeek(int y, int m, int d) //returns dan in a week (0-Monday,…,6-Sunday) 
{
    static int t[] = { 0,3,2,5,0,3,5,1,4,6,2,4 };
    y -= m < 3;
    return (y + y / 4 - y / 100 + y / 400 + t[m - 1] + d) % 7;
}
```

I would really appreaciate a help.
Thank you

Comment: Too broad: please provide more detail as where you need help.

Comment: It might be operating system specific, but the general ideas might be useful. Read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) and [strptime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html)

Comment: And the code of time related functions on Linux is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) e.g. in [musl-libc](https://musl-libc.org/). It certainly should inspire you. Actually, time is a very difficult topic (e.g. because of [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second)...) but you may want to convert it to `time_t`

Comment: Read more about [C date and time functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_date_and_time_functions)

Answer (score 1):

A good approach would be, to have a function that return each value you are interested in (`getYear`, `getMonth`, ...), that receives the line as input, and return the desired value:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define YEAR_LEN 4

typedef struct { 
  int year; 
  int month; 
  int day; 
  int hour; 
  int min; 
  int sec; 
  int dayInWeek; 
}tDateTime;

int getYear(char* p_line){
  char year[YEAR_LEN+1];
  strncpy(year, p_line+8, 4);
  year[YEAR_LEN] = '\0';   /* null character manually added */
  return atoi(year);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  char const* const fileName = argv[1];
  FILE* file = fopen("data.txt", "r");
  char line[256];
  tDateTime dt;

  while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
    printf("line: %s\n", line);
    dt.year = getYear(line);
    printf("%d\n", dt.year);
  }

  fclose(file);
  return 0;
}
```

After this is working you could also group all functions call into another function (something like `getData`) in that way the code is more organized and more maintainable.

Something like:

```
tDateTime getData(char* p_line){
  tDateTime res;
  res.year = getYear(p_line); 
  res.month = getMonth(p_line);
  return res;
}
```

Comment: Read more about [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing). Use [fgets](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) then [sscanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)

Comment: @JaroslavSýkora, What do you mean with "work only for ... certain line" ? this works for all lines in the file (until the `fgets` encounters EOF and then returns a null pointer which breaks the while). It you are talking about different structures in each line, you need to provide a description of the structure in the file, or at least more examples.